# Is it always necessary to first implement an interface for dependency injection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was trying to understand dependency injection and I am trying to figure out if its possible without creating interfaces?
If yes, than how can we call different beans as per the need?

Comment: It's not necessary, having interfaces is a recommended pattern to have because it's better to depend on abstractions (interfaces), rather than concrete implementations (implementation classes). In short, it's not required to create interfaces for your services

Comment: `If yes, than how can we call different beans as per the need?` - the same way you call different beans, when working with interfaces - using `@Qualifier`. Also, besides what Trash Can mentioned, depending on whether your component implements an interface, Spring will decide the proxying mechanism - with interface JDK dynamic proxies are used, cglib proxies otherwise.